# Displaying lots of JTextPanes?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jtextpane

I'm having a little trouble in determining the best design practices for displaying a bunch of JTextPanes. Let's say I have 1000 JTextPanes, each JTextPane contains a stylized message and I would like to display them one above the other, much like messages received in a chat. Would it be better to something involving a JTable and putting the panes inside there? or simply putting them all in a JPanel/JScrollPane? I would like to be able to remove and add JTextPanes, as well as select/focus a specific JTextPane. I've created a alpha-prototype(wouldn't even consider prototype) solution using JTable and creating custom models/renders, it just seems overly convoluted for what I'm trying to achieve.

Was wondering how acceptable it would be to just write a custom JPanel? Also I'm interested in the performance aspect of holding up to 10,000 JPanels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have 1 JTextPane and 10000 different Strings, populating the JTextPane with the given String as needed?

Comment: [example](http://i.imgur.com/GdSde.png)

Here is an example of what I'm going for. I'd like to be able to click on messages and "Delete/Hide" and potentially mouse over effects.

Comment: I'm with glowcoder on this (1+).  You can get your effects by adding a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to the single JTextPane.  Having many JTextPanes seems like senseless overkill.

Comment: @Random - That example makes sense. I would keep an internal state of what messages are displayed, and where in the textpane you are. I'm not familiar offhand if you can do that with JTextPane directly, or if you'll need to write your own listeners like @Eels suggested (I suspect you will have to write your own.)

Comment: Yeah, I searched around a little and found one way that looks promising. As a side note, I made a JList and added 20k JTextPanes (with the same text in the example image above) and aside from taking forever to load, it displayed fine and smoothely, but as camickr below stated, I realistically don't plan on ever having more than a few hundred messages in the chat window, I'll probably implement something like skype's "load more/last week". I'll see where I can get with a single JTextPane and if needed, *cringe* fall back to the many JTextPanes in some container...

Answer (score 2):

Displaying 10k text panes makes no sense to me. You would probably run out of resources. Some layout manager even have a limit on the number of components you can add. I think flow layout has a 512 limit so you would need to nest panels to achieve what you want which will add to the complexity.

Actually display 10K of anything doesn't make much sense to me either. How is the user ever going to scroll and find what they are looking for?

But if you do need something like this that allows you do tynamically add/remove items then I would look into a JTable. It already supports dynamic add/remove. Also you can even use the filtering features of JTable to make your application more usable.

I'm not sure why you say you need custom models and renderers. You can use HTML in a JTable for your styled messages.

Answer (score 0):

> ...stylized message and I would like to display them one above the other

The better way in this case is using JList with custom cell renderer.